# Spectator's Mode, Fog of War feature

Tags: league-of-legends

Wouldn't this feature allow for one team who has an active spectator watching the game without fog of war to give advices of incoming ganks, jungle invades, Baron, Dragon kills etc.?

The source of why I know theres a *Fog of war* feature is here [Next Patch: The Full Release of Spectator Mode!](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/next-patch-full-release-spectator-mode)

Comment: No. They put in a three minute delay for everyone who spectates.

Comment: True forget about the 3min delay =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a 3 minute delay in spectator mode, so the only cheats that people have cautioned about so far would be watching a ward get dropped.

Since a ward is alive for 3 minutes long, a spectator could communicate that to someone on a team, and the team would instantly know that the ward there was now gone.

Answer (score 3):

Since keeping track of the enemy team's warding is nigh impossible (you have to be looking RIGHT at the spot it goes down in order to pass along the information in a timely manner. Summoner's Rift is a large map and warding is not a one-person job.) the only real advantage that a spectator could give to a team would be the times that Red/Blue buff, Dragon, and Baron respawn.