# How can spectator mode be misused in League of Legends even with the 3 minute delay?

Tags: league-of-legends

Recently, League of Legends launched spectator mode. It made it possible for anyone to spectate a game going on with a delay of 3 minutes.

Is it possible to still cheat/misuse spectator mode? Perhaps with things that use longer than 3 minutes like spawn times, wards, inhibitors. What are the advantages you can gain by having a friend spectate a game?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Spectator's Mode, Fog of War feature](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64334/spectators-mode-fog-of-war-feature) the answer comment about the usage on wards.

Comment: @Michel This would not be a duplicate of that question as its asking even with the 3 minute delay

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate as the other question just scratches the surface.  It probably could have been re-worked into something better (more informed), but it already has answers.

Comment: they should make 4-5minutes delay. it would be completely useless then.

Answer (score 9):

The immediate exploit I can think of is destroying [Teemo](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Teemo_the_Swift_Scout)'s mushrooms.  Since they last for 10 minutes, a spectator could direct a player with an oracle's where to go to clear them.

A spectator could also help keep track of buff respawns, though this is typically handled by the jungler.

Though not directly useful, a spectator can watch a player's play-style and make best guesses about future moves.  Any pattern they see could potentially be used against that player.

Comment: I foresee many responses of 'That would have been useful to know 3min ago!' for most things :/

Comment: I think some other traps (Nidalee and Caitlyn) last over 3 minutes, though you can't kill them anyways.

Comment: @NickT Most likely the response would be "Oh, that trap. I already walked into that 2 minutes ago"

Answer (score 7):

The only real influence i can think of is:

It can be used for jungle respawn timers. Blue/Red buff have 5 minute respawn, Dragon 6, and Baron 7.
A spectator could follow the opposing team and give info on the respawn times of those objectives, so next time the opposing jungler tries to grab a buff or the opposing team tries to get dragon/baron, your team will already be waiting for him/them.

All other information won't really be useful 3 minutes later.

Answer (score 4):

Since it happends to be 3 minutes delay, it's easy to asume that the moment (give or take a few seconds) someone places a ward, the spectator knows that this ward just expired the moment it was laid out by current champion.

So basicly you can say "enemy dragon ward just expired" the moment it's placed out, for instance.

Not that much use obviously, but that actually means that you may get a moment when the enemy team doesn't see your jungler or similiar approach. Depending on how often they ward that same spot, that is.

Answer (score 2):

The most exploitable Spectator action has to do with Jungle camps and respawn timers.

A spectator could alert someone when a jungle camp such as Elder Lizard's camp has been cleared. The alerted player can then make better use of the time available on 1 ward to better intercept a player planning on clearing that jungle camp OR plan a strike at that camp for when the opposing prospector is busy away from that camp immediately after respawning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything exploitable. A spectator 3 minutes behind can't do anything that the players in the game couldn't/shouldn't have done in the intervening 3 minutes. Wards are too short a duration (they're gone in 3 minutes), and jungle camps up to and including Baron are visible if someone clears them (let alone knowing if the opposing team HAS Baron's buff). I think spectator mode is harmless, and a good way to improve and learn.

Comment: actually a way to abuse this is to look when wards are placed and let your friend know the ward is gone since he doesnt neceserally know a ward was placed or when it was placed.
while this won't really be a huge benefit it could still help with ganks etc

Comment: Wards have a 3 minute duration. If a spectator sees it get placed, it's already gone. The only thing it could inform is that there's possibly going to be ward there to replace it.

Comment: The spectator can alert his friend exactly when the ward disappears , because that's when he sees it placed.  This could help with ganks.

Comment: @Toast Most likely the ward will be replaced when it disappears, so the information is basically useless. "A ward disappeared at this position, there might or might not be a new ward so your gank might or might not fail"

Comment: Spectator to player:  They just warded river.  Player takes up position, ready to harass his opponent should they re-ward or informs the jungler that he can gank via river.  Knowing when you're opponents wards expire can be very useful information.

Comment: Since most of the player don't wait for wards to expire to re-ward, it could maybe not work.